# Show $|f(x + \delta_n) - f(x)| < \epsilon_n$ for $\epsilon_n$ independent of $x$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

For a sequence $\delta_n \rightarrow 0$ I need to show that there exists another sequence $\epsilon_n \rightarrow 0$ such that:

$$\sup_x|f(x + \delta_n) - f(x)| < \epsilon_n$$

What is required for this property to hold? Does it have a name?

If this did not have the supremum over $x$, I can find such an $\epsilon_n$ if the left and right limits are equal at all $x$. Is it sufficient that $f$ is bounded on it's domain? Is that too strong?

Comment: Uniform continuity of $f$ would be enough.

Comment: That's not clear to me, unfortunately. Uniform continuity goes the other way: for a $\epsilon$ I can find a $\delta$, but I want to show that there is an $\epsilon$ determined by some already chosen $\delta$. Further, this sequence should go to 0.

Comment: Is $\delta_n$ specific, or is it "for every sequence $\delta_n \to 0$ there exists ..."

Comment: $\delta_n$ is fixed

Comment: If $\delta_n$ is a subset of $ \mathbb{Q} $ then the function that equals 0 on all rationals and 1 on all irrationals satisfies what you want (the difference is 0 for all x).  So it actually depends on what specific $\delta_n$ we have

Comment: That's great, thanks @shortmanikos. Any idea what types of properties I could go after for $\delta_n$?

Answer (score 1):

Here is why uniform continuity is enough:

Let $\epsilon_n = 2 \sup | f (x+\delta_n) - f x |$.

This obviously satisfies the first condition you want. So we just need to show that $\epsilon_n \to 0$.

Let $\epsilon^* > 0$. By uniform continuity, we can find a $\delta^*$ so that whenever $\delta_n < \delta^*$, $\sup | f(x+\delta_n) - f x | < \epsilon^*$.

Then since $\delta_n \to 0$, we know $\delta_n < \delta^*$ for $n$ large enough.

But this means, for $n$ large enough, $\epsilon_n = 2 \sup | f(x+\delta_n) - f x | < 2 \epsilon^*$.

So $\epsilon_n \to 0$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Seems obvious, but I can't seem to prove that for any finite $\delta_n$, $\epsilon_n$ as you've defined it is finite if $f$ is uniformly continuous. Could you explain why this is?

Comment: In hindsight I was assuming $f$ was defined on an interval, so would be bounded. I'm not sure why I thought that, though, as it's not stated in the question. Good catch!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the confusion here; where is the boundedness of $f$ used in this answer?